# How to accumulate streaks in vector

Tags: r, vector, accumulate

I have a sequence of 0s and 1s in this manner:

```
xx <- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1)
```

I want to make a vector that accumulates the streak of the zeroes and adds the accumulated streak to the next possible value 1. The result in this specific vector should be:

```
yy <- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4)
```

What is the fastest and most efficient way to do this in R?

Answer (score 2):

This base R implementation may not be the most efficient implementation so it would be interesting to compare performance if others come up with answers.

### code

```
idx_add <- which(xx == 1 & c(NA, xx[-length(xx)]) == 0)
xx_rle <- rle(xx)
n_add <- xx_rle$lengths[xx_rle$values == 0]
yy <- xx
yy[idx_add] <- yy[idx_add] + n_add
```

### explanation

```
idx_add <- which(xx == 1 & c(NA, xx[-length(xx)]) == 0)
```

This line finds the indexes in `xx` that we will add to. Those are the places where we have a `1` preceded by at least one `0`. So we get `c(6, 8, 12)`.

```
xx_rle <- rle(xx)
```

Here we use the `rle()` (run-length encoding) function to get the length of all the streaks of consecutive values in the vector `xx`. `xx_rle` has two elements, `lengths`, the lengths of the streaks; and `values`, their values (`1`s and `0`s).

```
n_add <- xx_rle$lengths[xx_rle$values == 0]
```

Here we extract the streak lengths for only the streaks of zeroes.

```
yy <- xx
yy[idx_add] <- yy[idx_add] + n_add
```

Now create a copy of `xx` and add the zero streak lengths to the first `1` following the streak. This gives your desired result!

Answer (score 1):

One `base R` solution could be:

```
with(rle(xx), rep(values + c(0, head(lengths * (values == 0), -1)), lengths))

 [1] 1 1 1 0 0 3 0 2 0 0 0 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`:

Data:

```
xx <- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1)
```

Code:

```
yy <- as.data.frame(xx) %>% 
  mutate(group = ifelse(xx != 0, 1, 0),
         group = cumsum(group) + 1,
         group = ifelse(xx != 0, 0, group)) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(group = n() + 1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(yy = ifelse(xx != 0 & lag(xx) == 0, lag(group), xx),
         yy = ifelse(is.na(yy),xx,yy)) %>% 
  select(yy) %>% 
  pull()
```

Output:

```
[1] 1 1 1 0 0 3 0 2 0 0 0 4
```